# How to properly align strings in C# using String.Format()?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, format

guys, sorry to flood this website with such a boring question, but even after reading the documentation about C# and looking at their examples, I just can't seem to find an explanation for this.

Namely, I have a code like this:

```
        String s = "Hello";
        String n = "World";
        String s1 = "LALALALALALALA";
        String n1 = "heyy";
        String s2 = "sffsdfsfdsfsd";
        String n2 = "dsfsdfdsfdsfsdsd";

        String z = String.Format("{0,-20}{1,-10}", s, n);
        String z1 = String.Format("{0,-20}{1,-10}", s1, n1);
        String z2 = String.Format("{0,-20}{1,-10}", s2, n2);
```

(This code is simply meant to be a test)

Now, when I use:

```
        Console.WriteLine(z);
        Console.WriteLine(z1);
        Console.WriteLine(z2);
```

to write the output to the console, it works as I expected it to; 20 spaces are allocated to the string argument {0}, and the next spaces are allocated to the string argument {1}. However, when I run the exact same code in a form (as a MessageBox output, and even a TextBox text I get scrambled results. Argument {0} is okay, but then argument {1} starts at a seemingly random distance from the ending of {0}.

Is there a reason why this is happening? How can I fix it?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the font. Some fonts do not have the same width for all letters. If you try Consolas it will work fine.